# Lumen callback on completed download

Tags: php, laravel, download, response, lumen

I created a download route from which my client successfully downloads the file by adding the following code to /app/Http/routes.php:

```
$app->get('/dl', function() use ($app){
    return response()->download(getcwd() . "/targetfile");
});
```

but now I'd like to somehow have a callback be executed once the file transfer has been complete for a given instance of the get request. How would I do that?

To be a little more specific I'm trying to delete the file once it has been downloaded but this doesn't work:

```
$app->get('/dl', function() use ($app){
    unlink(getcwd() . "/targetfile");
    return response()->download(getcwd() . "/targetfile");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer to original Question

So in order to have a 'callback' once a response has been sent you use a so-called 'terminable' middleware.

In order for a middleware to be terminable:

1) it has to be global; I.E registered with the middleware function instead of the routeMiddleware

```
$app->middleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\Myterminable::class
]);
```

2) It has to have the method 'terminate ($request, $response)' this is the method that will be called once the response has been sent.

```
public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    // your code here
}
```

### An alternative

A global middleware seems to be like a waste of computation resources as it's called for every request/response pair so instead I just looked through Lumen's code to find that the download method is actually returning an instance of

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
```

On which I called

```
deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Which served my original goal

```
return response()->download(getcwd() . "/targetfile")->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register an `after Middleware` and apply it to your route.

> [Documentation about Middleware](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware)

Comment: I had already tried that. If you carefully look through the page you linked you'll notice that that response isn't actually sent before the after middleware is called. unlinking the file before making it available is not something I want to do for obvious reasons, I mentioned that in the question too.

Comment: Am I missing something ? if I do that all I get is a failed stat